# Swift: Thread 1 signal SIGABRT in class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Whenever I try to open a different view controller with a show segue it crashes with this error Swift: Thread 1 signal SIGABRT in class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, I don't know why.

Here's the code of the View Controller that I try to open:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AddEditVC: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


var item : Item? = nil

@IBOutlet weak var itemName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var imageHolder: UIImageView!

 let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if item != nil {
        itemName.text = item?.name
        imageHolder.image = UIImage(data: (item?.image)!)
    }


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func addImage(sender: AnyObject) {
    let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    pickerController.delegate = self
    pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    pickerController.allowsEditing = true

    self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


@IBAction func addImageFromCamera(sender: AnyObject) {
    let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    pickerController.delegate = self
    pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    pickerController.allowsEditing = true

    self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    self.imageHolder.image = image
}

@IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    if item != nil {
        editItem()
    } else {
        createNewItem()
    }
}

func createNewItem() {

    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Item", inManagedObjectContext: moc)
    let item = Item(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
    item.name = itemName.text
    item.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageHolder.image!)

    do {
        try moc.save()
    } catch {
        return
    }
}
func editItem () {

    item?.name = itemName.text
    item!.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageHolder.image!)

    do {
        try moc.save()
    } catch {
        return
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This error is usually appears when some of `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` is not assigned in the MainStoryboard.
Please check small circles before them. They should be grayed

Answer (score 0):

It's either what Andriy is saying, or you executed a PerformSegueWithIdentifier(***name***, nil) with the wrong identifier. Best to add a screenshot of your storyboard & original controller as well to give a definite answer.

Good luck!